# Spring не возвращает представление при определенных URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Если URL имеет вид localhost:8080/objectType, то Spring возвращает страницу .jsp, а URL вида localhost:8080/objectType/edit/{id} обрабатывается, но не возвращает представление. В консоли Glassfish'a при таких URL появляется

```
    [2017-03-12T23:53:07.134+0400] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet] [tid: _ThreadID=29 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1489348387134] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  PWC6117: File "null" not found]]
```

В общем все URL имеющие больше одного вложения (localhost:8080/имя/имя/и т.д.) не возвращают представление, а localhost:8080/имя нормально выводит jsp страницу

Помогите разобраться, проект на [GitHub'е](https://github.com/marat-yanvoev/01-08-2016_labs/tree/master/lab3)

Comment: А Вы уверены, что маппинг в web.xml правильно проведен? Так то ссылка по паттерну "/" на несуществующий сервлет - не слишком удачная идея.

Comment: На сколько я понимаю, в Spring все запросы обрабатывает DispatcherServlet, маппинг по паттерну "/" перехватывает все URL'ы. К тому же по всем URL'ам у меня выполняются нужные методы, но не возвращается представление.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблему я решил, и она крылась в файле dispatcher-servlet.xml. А именно:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="WEB-INF/pages/"
          p:suffix=".jsp"
    />
```

в префиксе я поставил "/" перед путем (`p:prefix="/WEB-INF/pages/"`) и все отображения стали выводится правильно.